# ASP.NET Core application doesn't work in IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, iis-express

I develop `ASP.NET Core 2.0` application which works on full framework `<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>`. Ususally to debug it I use `IIS Express`: just click green arrow in `Visual Studio 2017`.  It worked OK. But today it stopped working properly. Application runs but all requests hang. No exceptions are thrown. In `Windows Logs/Application` I see this:

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MY.APP.HERE' with physical root 'C:\code\MY.APP.HERE\' failed to start process with commandline 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe -argFile "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp35D5.tmp"', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 0.

Source of the message is **IIS Express AspNetCore Module**.

Any ideas what's the reason and how to fix it?

UPDATE: I see `A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\code\PATH.TO.APP.HERE\bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64\publish\'.` whily running `dotnet MyApp.exe`.

Comment: Is the application running in command line ? Normally if you are running the application in command line and try to run it using VS studio, it may be waiting for the dll to be released so that it can overwrite. That may be the cause.

Comment: See if the solution in [VS 2017 15.2 - Can't debug Asp.net projects](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/59516/vs-2017-152-cant-debug-aspnet-projects.html) helps.

Comment: @Sans All requests hang forever.

Answer (score -1):

iisreset - try it one time - As it was working before , hope it works !

Comment: How would IISReset help the user when their issue is with IIS Express?  IISReset only restarts IIS, I dont believe it has any interaction with IIS Express.